# Retrieving form submit content before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to calculate form submit URL before submit of form?

Currently I am doing it by this way:

```
var form = $('#myForm');
var action = form.attr('action');
var params = {};
$("input", form).each(function (index, input) { params[input.name] = input.value; });
var result = action + '?' + $.param(params);
```

But is there any better and simple way to doing that? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
var form = $('form');
var formAction = form.attr('action');
var result = formAction + '?' + form.serialize();
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/