# In JavaScript function, use dynamic form name to get access to a form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, function

In a JavaScript alert function, I want to see HTML form URL before it's submitted. I'm trying to accomplish as suggested by a StackOverFlow [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422487/retrieving-form-submit-content-before-submit).

In my scenario a HTML document can contain more than one form and form IDs are dynamically generated which has a convention: form_FORM_ID. For instance, if there are 2 forms, their IDs would be 'form_1' and 'form_2'. I'm trying to see form URL in a function to which a form ID is passed as parameter.

The [recommendation link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422487/retrieving-form-submit-content-before-submit) has following code:

```
var form = $('form');
var formAction = form.attr('action');
var result = formAction + '?' + form.serialize();
```

To get dynamic form name, I tried with(formID is passed as an argument to function):

1. `var formName = 'form_' + formID;
   var form = $('form[name=formName]');`
2. `var form = document.getElementById( 'form_' + formID );`

None of above two are working, please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your first example, you appear to have forgotten how to concatenate a variable with a string literal on line 2 despite managing it on line one. There's nothing obviously wrong with your second example.

Comment: Whoever down voted, please help me understand your action so that it gives me a chance to learn and improve in future. Thanks!

Comment: @Quentin 1. Is this what you meant - `var form = $('form['form_' + forMID]');` or `var form = $('form["form_" + formID]');`? Both do not work. 2. Even with my 2nd example, I'm unable to see `result`. Would be thankful for your inputs.

Comment: For the first, you really need to think about what the two different sets of quotes mean and where they need to go. For the second, as I said, there is still nothing obviously wrong. Whatever the problem is, there isn't enough code in the question to tell what it is. Read http://sscce.org/

Comment: I'm not into front-end development hence, the struggle. Anyhow, thanks again for your inputs, could help me in getting to the solution.

Comment: You don't need to be a front-end expert to deal with nested quotes. As for the rest, as I've said already, there isn't enough information in the question to tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your method 1

```
var formName = 'form_' + formID;
var form = $('form[name=formName]');
```

but you need to make these changes

```
var formName = 'form_' + formID;
var form = $('form[name="' + formName + '"]');
```